# `Cannot find module 'undefined'` with require.context after electron build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron, electron-builder

I am using electron with react and as packager electron-builder, all on the latest version.

When using require.context() in my development build its works just like intended, but when building the app it throws `Cannot find module "undefined"`, is this because webpack is not packaging with the build? Another way of importing all images in a folder on runtime would also help if this seems unfixable.

the code throwing the error:

```js
function importAll(r) {
  let images = {};
  r.keys().forEach((item, index) => { images[item.replace('./', '')] = r(item); });
  return images;
}

try {
   Banners = importAll(require.context('../../../Assets/Banners', false, /\.(jpg)$/));
   Headers = importAll(require.context('../../../Assets/Headers', false, /\.(jpg)$/));
} catch (err) { console.error(`A problem has occurred while loading library images:\n${err.stack}`) }
```

I am packaging the app with this config:

```
"build": {
    "appId": "666",
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis",
      "icon": "public/icon.ico"
    },
    "files": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "extraFiles": [
      {
        "from": "src/Assets",
        "to": "Assets",
        "filter": [
          "**/*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

the file tree looks like this:

```
root
├───Assets
│   ├───Banners
│   │   └───image1.jpg
│   └───Headers
│       └───image1.jpg
├───Locales
├───Resources
│   └───app.asar
└───Launcher.exe
```